# How to write MDX Query for getting grouped results

Tags: sql-server, mdx, olap, saas

I have Cube where data is aggregated and all I need to have count of records against each 2 digit zip code.

Attached image shows my cube hierarchies and measures.

[image: OlapCube]

I applied query like :

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].NoOfConsignments as Count(([Consignment].[Target Address Name].[Target Address Name]))
select filter([Consignment].[Distribution Area].[Zip2], [Consignment].[Distribution Area].[Target Address Country] = "94") on rows,
{[Measures].NoOfConsignments} on columns
from [RebellOlap]
where ({[Consignment].[Distribution Area].[Target Address Country].&[94]})
```

but is throwing an error :

"The Distribution Area hierarchy already appears in the Axis1 axis"

I re-structured and formulated following sub-select query in the following way :

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].NoOfConsignments as Count(([Consignment].[Target Address Name].[Target Address Name]))
Select
NON EMPTY [Measures].NoOfConsignments on columns,
NON EMPTY [Consignment].[Distribution Area].[Zip2] on rows
FROM  ( 
    SELECT {[Consignment].[Distribution Area].[Zip2],[Consignment].[Distribution Area].[Target Address Country].&[94]}
    FROM [RebellOlap] 
   )
```

but it also returned me the 'ambiguity error'.

**all I need Output in following manner**

[image]

**Edit**

AllConsignments in Germany

[image]

All Consignments in Germany against specific Zip Code

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the pre defined measure `Num. Consignments`?

Comment: No no that is Num. Consignments against specific Customer (here [Consignment.Target Address. Target Address] and there are 100's of customers ( or Target addresses ) in particular Zip Code area.

So, all I want to have No Of Consignments against particular zip code

Like 38->150, 54-->300 etc. ( In 38 zip code, there are multiple corresponding customers and other summarized/aggregated data )

Comment: see my edits...It will help to understand what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just applied filter for all zip codes and introduce "Range" as Operator with 'Filter Expression' and it worked!!

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[ConsignmentCount] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([Consignment].[Distribution Area].[Zip2].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( [Consignment].[Distribution Area].[Zip2].&[94]&[0]&[01] : [Consignment].[Distribution Area].[Zip2].&[94]&[9]&[99] ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [RebellOlap])
```

Comment: Your solution is contradictory to what you specified in the question. Why are all the countries included here?

Comment: I am sorry, this CountryId would be fed from code ( e.g CountryId = 94 )

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edits, I feel below should work out for you:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.NumConsignment as
COUNT
     (
      NonEmpty
             (
              [Consignment].[Target Address Name].[Target Address Name].MEMBERS, 
              ([Consignment].[Distribution Area].CURRENTMEMBER, Measures.[Num. Consignments])
             )
     )

SELECT [Consignment].[Distribution Area].[Zip2].MEMBERS on 1,
Measures.NumConsignment ON 0
FROM 
(
 SELECT [Consignment].[Distribution Area].[Target Address Country].&[94] ON 0
 FROM [RebellOlap]
)
```

While the rest of the code is pretty standard, there is one part which might need explanation.

```
      NonEmpty
             (
              [Consignment].[Target Address Name].[Target Address Name].MEMBERS, 
              ([Consignment].[Distribution Area].CURRENTMEMBER, Measures.[Num. Consignments])
             )
```

This is returning a set of those Target addresses for the *current* zip for whom the *num of consignments* is not empty( i.e. <>0)

Comment: It is returning output 
but corresponding to each zip code it has an entry "#Error"

and Error description is : 

"The CURRENTMEMBER function expects a hierarchy expression for the 1 argument. A member expression was used."

Comment: Oops! Corrected. Try now.

Comment: No it is giving me the same error after trying the modifying but I applied query on my answer and it is giving me right results.

Comment: Earlier I was incorrectly applying the `CURRENTMEMBER` function. It was corrected. I am surprised it still threw the SAME error. But glad you found a solution.